# JavaScript regular expressions anything before match

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-formatting

I'm completely new to regular expressions in JavaScript and this is probably the first time I'm using it, I wanted to know how to get the values **before** and **after** a **colon** or **hash** and store their values into a variables like this:

```
var str = 'name[:|#]result';
// before and after values
var trigger = 'name';
var value = 'result';
// logs: name result
console.log(trigger + ' ' + value);
```

Comment: [Google search (click this link)](https://www.google.de/search?q=introduction+regular+expressions+javascript)

Comment: I found this page from your search http://codular.com/regex thanks it's a lot easier to understand than just watching tutorials, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do what you want (now with a regex)

```
var str1 = 'name:result',
    str2 = 'name#result';
// get anything before ':result'
var matcher = new RegExp(/(.*)[:|#](.*)/);
var minResult1 = str1.match(matcher),
    minResult2 = str2.match(matcher);

// This will split the results to: 
// [fullstring, name, result]

console.log(minResult1[1], minResult1[2]); 
console.log(minResult2[1], minResult2[2]);
```

It splits the string based on the text ':result', and grabs whatever came behind it.

New Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/qjdrjozx/1/

Comment: Thanks and this is a great answer but the reason i wish to use regex is because not only ami looking good what is behind the colon but i also want the value that comes after it.

Comment: I've updated my question so you can understand more sorry for not being as clear the first time.

Comment: This is too great thanks for the update / edit bro just what i needed once again sorry if my original question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<trigger>.+?)(?=[:#])|(?<=[:#])(?<value>.+)
```

You can do this through simple regex using lookaheads and lookbehinds.See demo.Grab the capture or group.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/21

Comment: Thanks for the awnser bro great one :-)

Comment: Awesome link Just finished reading it and i understand regex better now.

Comment: Look-aheads should be avoided when they are not needed, they are not very performant.